# jquery-inputmask stops working after ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajaxform, renderpartial, jquery-inputmask

I am submitting a form with `remote:true`. The request goes and come, the `format: js` is loaded as well.

The problem is that I have a input which uses a mask powered with `jquery-inputmask` and this mask stops working after the partial rendering of the form.

I've tried to solve this by many ways, like using inline data attributes or loading it with jquery. None of them worked. Everytime the form is "reloaded" after the ajax request, the script stops working.

I understand this is related to the elements and the DOM loading, but I can't figure out a way of fixing this.

Any help?

Comment: Can you share your view code?

Comment: You should call the binding of `jquery-inputmask` to the input field everytime after the partial rendering of the form.